# The From phone number is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number

Tags: twilio

I need to send SMS messages from a website.
I made an account to Twilio and I wanted to try if I really get a message from them.

I use this code that I founded on the net:

```
const string accountSid = "....";
const string authToken = "....";
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var to = new PhoneNumber("+40740539623");
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            to,
            from: new PhoneNumber("+1402-704-3438"),
            body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?");
```

AccountSid and AuthToken are correct. But I keep getting the error message that the From number *is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.'*

I tried to use the number that I have on my Twilio account, I only have a test account, so I thought that I can use this number to send test SMS.
[image]

Can you please advise what I'm missing here? How can I send test SMS from Twilio? From Trial Account I can't send messages?

Exception:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

pass the phone numbers in as a string in the format "+18001234567", where +1 is the US country code, and whatever after is the 10 digit US phone number.

Also, I have no idea what the +4 area code is you're using in your to number, but you may have a number that doesn't support international SMS. I've only worked with US numbers, both to and from, so can't offer any guidance on how to work with international SMS.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Thanks for the answer! I think you're right, the from number needs the dashes removed, it should be `+14027043438`. Just FYI, `+40` is the [Romanian country code](http://www.wtng.info/wtng-40-ro.html).

Comment: @philnash Thanks for you time. I've updated the question with the exception that I got. I removed the '-' from the phone number, but still I got the error. What do you mean by removing the dashes? The PhoneNumber waits a string, Can you please advise? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using your production or test credentials?